# Load svmlight format error

Tags: python, import, load, format, svmlight

When I try to use the [svmlight python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svmlight/) with data I already converted to svmlight format I get an error. It should be pretty basic, I don't understand what's happening. Here's the code:

```
import svmlight
training_data = open('thedata', "w")
model=svmlight.learn(training_data, type='classification', verbosity=0)
```

I've also tried:

```
training_data = numpy.load('thedata')
```

and

```
training_data = __import__('thedata')
```

Comment: What error do you get? Is there a traceback that you can post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you are truncating your data file when you open it because you are specifying write mode `"w"`. This means that there will be no data to read.

Anyway, you don't need to read the file like that if your data file is like the one in this [example](https://bitbucket.org/wcauchois/pysvmlight/raw/d8f3bb76d016fbab8d01f53b0bf84560bbbe6e05/examples/data.py), you need to import it because it is a python file. This should work:

```
import svmlight
from data import train0 as training_data    # assuming your data file is named data.py
# or you could use __import__()
#training_data = __import__('data').train0

model = svmlight.learn(training_data, type='classification', verbosity=0)
```

You might want to compare your data against that of the example.

***Edit after data file format clarified***

The input file needs to be parsed into a list of tuples like this:

```
[(target, [(feature_1, value_1), (feature_2, value_2), ... (feature_n, value_n)]),
 (target, [(feature_1, value_1), (feature_2, value_2), ... (feature_n, value_n)]),
 ...
]
```

The svmlight package does not appear to support reading from a file in the SVM file format, and there aren't any parsing functions, so it will have to be implemented in Python. SVM files look like this:

```
<target> <feature>:<value> <feature>:<value> ... <feature>:<value> # <info>
```

so here is a parser that converts from the file format to that required by the svmlight package:

```
def svm_parse(filename):

    def _convert(t):
        """Convert feature and value to appropriate types"""
        return (int(t[0]), float(t[1]))

    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line.startswith('#'):
                line = line.split('#')[0].strip() # remove any trailing comment
                data = line.split()
                target = float(data[0])
                features = [_convert(feature.split(':')) for feature in data[1:]]
                yield (target, features)
```

And you can use it like this:

```
import svmlight

training_data = list(svm_parse('thedata'))
model=svmlight.learn(training_data, type='classification', verbosity=0)
```

Comment: When I try the open with "r" I get `TypeError: expected list of documents` .
When I try the import I get     `-1 0:1.173286269861675 1:0.4524566925178124 2:-0.9622895995173304 3:-0.0323228512901514 4:-0.3883630237637885 5:0.05964858946340369 6:0.4476052015809368 7:0.4476052012718441 8:0.03136114112311881 9:0.4500600446286898 10:0.4492788390876735 11:0.4479268098079717 12:0.4475026647089226 13:0.4479050146233448 14:0.4476815332854934 15:0.4474691649775809 16:0.4565717543476677 17:0.4475921191001453
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

(the above is an example of an instance in my data file)

Comment: The data file is not in fact exactly equal, because I don't have structs, just the data. I used scikit learn array to svmlight format conversion function, I'm not sure how I can transform the data in a file with a struct instead...

Comment: Thank you. I've accepeted your answer, you helped me seeing the problem and you solved it. I get always zero when testing the constructed SVM model with the resulting data. I tried parsing it myself also just to be sure, and ended up achieving always zero when testing the model. I am not sure if both our data conversions are still wrong or if there's a problem with the implementation I'm using, but I suspect it's something else, so I guess this issue is closed. I'll update if I find out why I am getting always zero (I've tried the same data on other algorithms and the results are good) .

Comment: The data conversion is correct - it works on both test files available at http://download.joachims.org/svm_light/examples/example1.tar.gz. I also don't think that there is a problem with the implementation as the model file written by `svmlight.write_model()` contains data. Have you tested with [`simple.py`](https://bitbucket.org/wcauchois/pysvmlight/src/d8f3bb76d016fbab8d01f53b0bf84560bbbe6e05/examples/simple.py)?

Comment: Yes, simply.py works as expected. Only with this data it doesn't work, I really don't know why. LIBSVM and LIBLINEAR work fine. I also tried changing  `target = float(data[0])` to  `target = int(data[0])` , because it could possibly only accept integers, but the results continue the same: all targets are 0 when trying to classify. I just noticed that the [data in the examples](https://bitbucket.org/wcauchois/pysvmlight/src/d8f3bb76d016fbab8d01f53b0bf84560bbbe6e05/examples/data.py?at=default) has targets of 1 and -1 in the train data, and only 0 in the test data, which doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I have uploaded the data, which I think is fine, but just in case you want to test it: [training data](http://bitshare.com/files/sk0ozbxq/poydf_train.html) [test data](http://bitshare.com/files/y5wnar34/poydf_test.html)