# What does each item mean in svmLight Format

Tags: python, format, svm, svmlight

I am very confused about what each part means in a svmLight data format.
For example:

(label/target, [(feature, value), ...], queryid)

Does the label means the rank of the data and queryid is the id of the object?

For example:
for the following item:

2 qid:1 1:4.000000 2:2.772589 3:0.266667 4:0.258154 5:37.330565 6:11.431241 7:37.307017 8:1.213630 9:21.342267 10:10.842279 11:15.634736 12:2.749495 13:-39.467448 14:-37.791635 15:-38.002289 16:14.000000 17:5.634790 18:0.063927 19:0.063290 20:28.303065 21:9.340024 22:24.809801 23:0.231553 24:52.396216 25:1.692954 26:16.619600 27:2.810583 28:-45.733775 29:-44.612550 30:-44.823263 31:18.000000 32:6.579251 33:0.076923 34:0.076079 35:27.701632 36:9.139690 37:23.819476 38:0.277200 39:67.283604 40:1.847508 41:19.559974 42:2.973485 43:-44.687666 44:-43.467574 45:-43.302044 #docid = 346319

Does 2 means the rank/ the target value of the object? Then what does qid or docid means for the file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The leading number is indeed the "target" of this object. The `qid:1` part is used in constraining pairwise difference between such objects. The `docid`, or rather everything after the final `#` is an info string that

> can be used to pass additional information to the kernel (e.g. non feature vector data)

([source](http://svmlight.joachims.org/)).

The general format for each object is given in the official source, under the heading "How to use":

```
<line> .=. <target> <feature>:<value> <feature>:<value> ... <feature>:<value> # <info>
<target> .=. +1 | -1 | 0 | <float> 
<feature> .=. <integer> | "qid"
<value> .=. <float>
<info> .=. <string>
```

Note that the format you specify

```
(label/target, [(feature, value), ...], queryid)
```

is that of [pysvmlight](https://bitbucket.org/wcauchois/pysvmlight), a Python binding to the SVM-Light support vector machine library made by Thorsten Joachims, which I quoted earlier. You'll need to write a parser to parse the datafiles native to svmlight into the format that pysvmlight uses. There is at least [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25666050/2476444) on StackOverflow, even though it does not take into account the `qid`, but it shouldn't be too difficult to add when you read that parser's code.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!